# XML as data store. Insert, remove, delete

Tags: java, xml, database, editing

I was planning to use XML to store the data for a Java DVD database application I'm writing. I know that the word "database" is right there in the title, but XML just seemed so much more portable, was human readable and (I assumed before looking into it) simpler to implement.

Parsing XML seems to be the easiest thing in the world... even creating a new XML file isn't much trouble, but changing records, inserting them or deleting them, I can only see to do by creating a fresh XML file.

Am I missing something? Or is the thing that I'm missing that I should switch over to a database format (but there's some wonderful database format I've not heard of, that's totally portable and users won't need to install something separate to use :) )

Comment: Well. There is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Portable, no separate installation required, reasonable fast and flexible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the most popular way to use a file as a database is probably with sqlite  http://www.sqlite.org/ and that's what i would use if i were solving your problem (it's pretty much a standard SQL database, but uses just one file as storage).  another, pure-java option is apache derby http://db.apache.org/derby/

however, pure xml databases do exist (and were quite fashionable about 10 years ago - the "nosql" of their time) - the associated standards are xpath http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath and xquery http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xquery . i haven't used it, but it seems like basex http://basex.org/open-source/ is an open-source implementation that you could use (and it does claim to provide ACID guarantees - http://basex.org/products/ ).

if you're more familiar with xml than sql i don't see any great harm in using an xml database for a small project.  just structure your code so that most of the program doesn't care what the storage is (ie by providing a neutral interface).  then if xml doesn't work out you can switch to sql by re-implementing just that interface and leaving the rest of your program alone (and if it does work, post back here saying so - it would be interesting to know).

Comment: All helpful answers, but I'm going to pick this one 'cause it gave me a whole bunch of things to look into :) Thanks to everyone :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to have a web-based front end, it seems that a regular database is the way to go as the back end.  I don't believe your users would have a need to download anything new, since that's all taken care of server-side.  A real database also has the ACID advantage over a pseudobase; it should be atomic, consistent, isolated, and durable, and I can't imagine XML would be a good substitute in those respects.